# How can I translate django models

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

How can I translate django models without use `verbose_name` argument on each field? Occur a practicing to inherit all models by an intermediate class which looking for adding new fields and automatically supply it an arg `verbose_name` by name of field? Or is a best practice to integrate translation into the forms? Maybe I should supply every model `verbose_name` attribute on create?

I don't want to do like this:

```
class Currency(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name=_("name"))
    symbol=models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name=_("symbol"))
    iso_4217=models.CharField(max_length=3)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name=_(u'currency')
        verbose_name_plural=_(u'currencies')
```

I want to do something like this:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    __setattr__(self, name, value):
        ''' Some needles parts of method was cutted out to make it easily
        '''
        value.verbose_name=_(name)
        value.verbose_name_plural=_("%ss" % name)
        self.super(BaseModel, name, value)

class Currency(models.Model):
    ''' Every field of this class whould be supplied by verbose_name and verbose_name_plural
    '''
    name=models.CharField(max_length=32)
    symbol=models.CharField(max_length=32)
    iso_4217=models.CharField(max_length=3)
```

Maybe django has something solution in self?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to read [this article](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/).

To localize your app, you need to wrap every eglish string to an argument of a function ugettext, e.g. `'foo'` -> `ugettext('foo')`.

Then you can run `manage.py makemessages --locale=<locale>`, where `<locale>` is a [language code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/#term-language-code).

It makes a file inside ./locale/language_code/*.po and you need to translate string in this file to your language, e.g.

```
#: env_website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.6.egg/django  /conf/global_settings.py:44
msgid "Arabic"
msgstr "Арабский"
```

After that you need to run command `manage.py compilemessages`

That's it.

Comment: Thx, for the answer, but I'm oppose trying to avoid of adding `verbose_name` to each model and every field of model. Want to manage translation of the models in one place. Like in example, above.

Comment: I see, that I adviced a trivial way that doesn't compatible with your request.

Comment: I think you need this: https://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

You can override Model's [add_to_class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L254) class method. It is called for every added field.

See how [contribute_to_class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L253) in fields sets `verbose_name` from attribute name if it is not provided.

However, I would not recommend this approach as `gettext` could not create translations catalogs for this fields.